# Create a recursive list structure with Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I am trying to create a recursive list `<ul>` in Blazor, The way that I did looks logical but I got a strange behavior, this is my code:

Class Element that represent `ul li`:

```cs
public class Element
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Element Parent { get; set; }
    public int Index { get; set; }
}
```

ULComponent.Razor:

```html
@if (DataItems?.Count() > 0)
{
  <ul>
        @foreach (var element in DataItems)
        {
            var children = DataItems.Where(e => e.Parent == element).OrderBy(e => e.Index);
            <li>
                @element.Title

                @if (children.Count() > 0)
                {
                    <UlComponent DataItems="children" />
                }
            </li>
        }
  </ul>
}
```

ULComponent.Razor.cs, code behind:

```cs
public partial class ULComponent
{
    [Parameter]
    public IEnumerable<Element> DataItems { get; set; }
}
```

Razor page code behind:

```cs
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    var root = new Element { Title = "Root", Index = 1 };
    var element1 = new Element { Title = "Element 1", Index = 1, Parent = root };
    var element2 = new Element { Title = "Element 2", Index = 2, Parent = root };
    var element3 = new Element { Title = "Element 3", Index = 3, Parent = root };
    var element11 = new Element { Title = "Element 1.1", Index = 1, Parent = element1 };
    var element12 = new Element { Title = "Element 1.2", Index = 2, Parent = element1 };
    var element121 = new Element { Title = "Element 1.2.1", Index = 1, Parent = element12 };
    var element21 = new Element { Title = "Element 2.1", Index = 1, Parent = element2 };
    var element22 = new Element { Title = "Element 2.2", Index = 2, Parent = element2 };
    var element31 = new Element { Title = "Element 3.1", Index = 1, Parent = element3 };
    Elements = new List<Element> {root, element1, element2, element3, element11,
           element12, element121, element21, element22, element31};
}
```

Razor page:

```html
@if (Elements != null)
{
    <div class="row">
        <ULComponent DataItems="Elements"/>
    </div>
    
}
```

The result of the code up.

```
Root
    Element 1
    Element 2
    Element 3
Element 1
    Element 1.1
    Element 1.2
Element 2
    Element 2.1
    Element 2.2
Element 3
    Element 3.1
Element 1.1
Element 1.2
    Element 1.2.1
Element 1.2.1
Element 2.1
Element 2.2
Element 3.1
```

I am trying to get this:

```
Root
Element 1
    Element 1.1
    Element 1.2
        Element 1.2.1
Element 2
    Element 2.1
    Element 2.2
Element 3
    Element 3.1
```

Comment: Shouldn't `<MyReport DataItems="children" />` be a `<ULComponent />`?

Comment: Sorry, I correct it!

Comment: FWIW, the result you get is what I would expect from your code. In the first loop, you will have a `<li>` for every item in your list, and for each one of them, a `<ul>` with only their immediate children. You somehow need to pass the entire collection to the child component if you don't want to lose the children's children

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Components can be nested inside themselves.  So long as you have properly self-referenced data, then it's quite easy to unpack it.  The nice thing about this is if you later decide that you want to categorize "Animals" as "Things," you can just change its ParentID to 8, and you're done.

**Element.cs**

```
public class Element
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int? ParentID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**Parent.razor**

```
<CascadingValue Value="Items">
    <ul>
        <RecursiveUI ParentID="null" />
    </ul>
</CascadingValue>
 
@code {
    List<Element> Items;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Items = new List<Element>
        {
            new Element { ID=1, Name="Animals", ParentID = null},
            new Element { ID=2, Name="Mammals", ParentID = 1},
            new Element { ID=3, Name="Birds", ParentID = 1},
            new Element { ID=4, Name="Bears", ParentID = 2},
            new Element { ID=5, Name="Beavers", ParentID = 2},
            new Element { ID=6, Name="Eagles", ParentID = 3},
            new Element { ID=7, Name="Parakeets", ParentID = 3},
            new Element { ID=8, Name="Things", ParentID = null},
            new Element { ID=9, Name="Yo-yos", ParentID = 8},
            new Element { ID=10, Name="Computers", ParentID = 8}
        };
    }
}
```

**RecursiveUI.razor**

```
@foreach (var item in Items.Where(i => i.ParentID == ParentID))
{
    <li>@item.Name
        @if (Items.Where(c=>c.ParentID == item.ID).Any())
        {
           <ul>
               <RecursiveUI ParentID="item.ID"/>  @*THIS IS THE MAGIC.*@
           </ul>
        }
    </li>
}

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int? ParentID { get; set; }

    [CascadingParameter]
    List<Element> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That `[CascadingParameter]` is a thing I'm happy to have learned today!

Answer (score 2):

> Not a full answer but I can't put the code snippets in a comment.

Is there any reason why you can't restructure your class as follows?

```
public class Element
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Element Parent { get; set; }
    public int Index { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Element> SubElements { get; set; }
}
```

It saves a lot of Linq querying to get the sublists and you can then
recursively iterate through the parent nodes and build out your control.

Answer (score 2):

Forgive me for adding another answer, but for very long lists, it might be worth adding some simple function to choose which branches to display.

From my other answer, but change the following:

```
public class Element
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int? ParentID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsOpened {get; set;}  /*Add This*/
}
```

and change **RecursiveUI.razor** as follows:

```
<li style="cursor:pointer" @onclick="() => item.IsOpened = !item.IsOpened">@item.Name
    @if (item.IsOpened && Items.Where(c => c.ParentID == item.ID).Any())
    {
        <ul>
            <RecursiveUI ParentID="item.ID" />
        </ul>
    }
</li>
```

Comment: Blazor's surprisingly efficient.  You can try setting a breakpoint in Recursive UI, and see that it's not re-building all the items each time.  Or try making a much longer list (like hundreds of items), but it's really not going to make a difference.  I've done trees like this where the text of the deepest rank was ENTIRE BOOK TEXT (like Wizard of oz, etc.), and Blazor didn't even blink.

Comment: Thank you. This is a good structure, especially if there is potentially a lot of data and the data is fetched by each individual component instead of just passed long as a huge list of items.

Answer (score 1):

You say your code looks logical, but think of it this way:

On your first iteration, you create an `<ul>`, with one `<li>` for every item in your list, which gives:

```
Root
Element 1
Element 2
Element 3
Element 1.1
Element 1.2
Element 1.2.1
Element 2.1
Element 2.2
Element 3.1
```

*Note that this already goes against what you want*

Then, for every item, you create a `ULComponent` with its immediate children, so for `Root`, you create an `ULComponent` with `children={Element 1, Element 2, Element 3}`. This creates an `<ul>` with 3 `<li>`s:

```
Root
    Element 1
    Element 2
    Element 3
Element 1
Element 2
Element 3
Element 1.1
Element 1.2
Element 1.2.1
Element 2.1
Element 2.2
Element 3.1
```

You won't go further, as none of those three element has any children *in the current list* (which is `Element 1, Element 2, Element 3`).

This is why you should either rethink your `Element` class to include children, or find a way to pass two parameters instead of one: **current element** *and* **full list**

Untested, but an idea of how it could look:

```cs
public partial class ULComponent
{
    [Parameter]
    public Element Item { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public IEnumerable<Element> DataItems { get; set; }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    @Item.Title
    @foreach (var child in DataItems.Where(e => e.Parent == Item).OrderBy(e => e.Index))
    {
      <ULComponent Item="child" DataItems="DataItems" />
    }
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks alot for help, please don't delete your solution for me and for other people!